# Custom syntax highlighter for HTML with line numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I want to have a large input text area that I can type in something. Just like in JavaScript IDEs, when I type in syntax, I want them to be highlighted as we type. In the left hand side, line number should be displayed. Because I'm using this not for programming languages, I want to add new syntax. I found some JavaScript and CSS modules like `prismjs`, `rainbows`. But I'm not sure how can I use these to a something like `<textarea></textarea>` where I can type.

Comment: Codemirror will help you in this matter.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You should try [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/). Their web contains all the necessary documentation to implement it in your website.